# Return error of [: illegal number: 100k

Tags: command-line, scripts

I run a program which a program in Ubuntu terminal with input as follow

> 100k
>
> ExampleFile
>
> ~/

and program code

```
#!/bin/sh
#!/bin/bash
​
echo "File size you want to archive"
read size
​
echo "File name to archive"
read name
​
echo "Path to archive"
read path
​
echo "Size is: $size filename is: $name path is: $path"
​
a=99
b=100
​
if [ "$size" -lt $a ] #line 19
then
    echo "File is small. Refused to archive"
elif [ "$size" -lt $b ] #line 22
then
    find "$path" -type f -size "$size" | tar cvzf ~/"$name".tar.gz
else
    echo "Wrong input"
fi
```

After executing, it return error of

> ./try.sh: 18: [: Illegal number: 100k
>
> ./try.sh: 21: [: Illegal number: 100k

can someone explain what is the problem with this code?

Comment: remove ```#!/bin/sh```, one shebang is enough.

Comment: already remove, same error caught when executing the program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `numfmt` to convert human-readable string to number.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

echo "File size you want to archive"
read size

echo "File name to archive"
read name

echo "Path to archive"
read path

echo "Size is: $size filename is: $name path is: $path"

a=99000
b=100000

num=$(numfmt --from auto "$size" 2>&-)

if [[ -z $num ]]
then
    echo "Invalid size!"
    exit 1
fi

if (( $num < $a )) #line 19
then
    echo "File is small. Refused to archive"
elif (( $num <= $b )) #line 22
then
    find "$path" -type f -size +$((num - 1))c ! -size +${b}c | tar cvzf ~/"$name".tar.gz
else
    echo "file is too large!"
fi
```

Comment: ```size``` in your form will match exact size, in this form you will get a range, size to b.

Comment: I try to apply your answer but after executing, there's some error for the if and elif statement saying ((: < 99000: syntax error: operand expected  (error token is " < 99000 " and same for this line elif (( $num <= $b ))

Comment: missed an exit, fixed

Comment: It works! Thank you so much for your help!